# How to add a custom culture (en-cn) to Azure AppService (WebApp)?

Tags: azure

I have a task to add a new custom culture (en-cn). There isn't a problem from coding side and I used CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder for this but I can't create this culture on the Azure AppService, Register method throws an exception and requires extra-permissions.

Have you met something similar?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I think you want to make your app globalization and localization via [`CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder?view=netframework-4.8) Class in .NET Framework. However, as the figure below, it requires [`sysglobl.dll`](https://www.processlibrary.com/en/directory/files/sysglobl/304912/) which is a system call that can not be used in Azure App Service (WebApp).

[image]

The reason is [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) said in [`Azure Web App sandbox`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), as below.

[image]

To fix it, you can consider to use other solution to support internationalization (i18n) in your ASP.NET website. Please refer to the blog [Understanding Globalization and Localization in .NET](https://dhavalupadhyaya.wordpress.com/tag/getglobalresourceobject-in-different-lan/) to realize it.